# What would be a good method to find popular, low rated apps on the google play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Apart from just scouring through the charts and clicking on each app individually. I calculate that would take a full week to complete.

I can't find any site that lets you sort the apps by rating, making this tough to achieve... if it's possible at all.

Thanks!

Comment: How come popular apps be low rated? :-O

Comment: Hang on, are you talking about doing this automatically? Google Play Store is proprietary and no way of automating it or by programmatic means to do so as that is a violation of Terms & conditions of the Play store. Google prohibits usage of screenscraping etc on that and would shoot down anyone doing that.

Comment: No. I'm not talking about that. There are many sites that have the data as well. appbrain, appannie, etc. I'm wondering if there's on that would allow sorting by rating which would then allow finding low rated apps. I can't find any so far.

Comment: Or there could be some other way of finding these insights that I'm not aware of - hence the question.